# Regular expression to get specific numbers from a string with a condition

Tags: regex

I wish to extract “2” `(00000002)`the from below string. But the condition is that the string should start with *X1. I wish to have a generic regular expression as in if there will any number it should return it.

```
*X19845674367       00000002+000000000000123000KGS000CDH000002
```

I have tried this regex -

```
(?<=\d)([1-9])\d*(?=\+)
```

But it returns number all the strings,
But I wish have from a specific tag e.g. *X1

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Then, try `^\*X1\w*\s+0*([1-9]\d*)`. See https://regex101.com/r/ZaC1cU/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew- thanks. But it returns the entire string till ‘2’. I wish to extract only ‘2’ not the entire string.

Comment: So just get Group 1 value, why do you use a capturing group in your regex if you do not actually return only the group value? Show your code.

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use capturing groups, then another valid expression is this one:

```
(?<=\*[^\s]+\s+0*)([1-9]+[0-9]*)(?=\+)
```

If *X1 is a fixed requirement, just put it in front after the *:

```
(?<=\*X1[^\s]+\s+0*)([1-9]+[0-9]*)(?=\+)
```

Instead of `([1-9]+[0-9]*)`, creating a capturing group, you can also leave out the brackets - `[1-9]+[0-9]*`, works either way.

The expression allows for anything in front, then some spaces, then capturing the first number, but ignoring 0 prefixes.

You can play around with it and look at the in-depth explainations using the demo here:
https://regex101.com/r/gyMx2i/1

Comment: This will match strings that do not start with `*X1`

Comment: I also updated the answer in case *X1 is a hard requirement

Answer (score 1):

```
^\*X1.*?(\d)\+
```

This **regular expression** searches for a **string** that starts with `*X1`, any **number of characters** until it finds a **sequence of digits** followed by a `+` sign. The digits are saved in a group, which can be accessed using the group method of the match object.

If **no match** is found, you get `None`.

Comment: Thanks. It didn’t return anything. I wish to extract only ‘ 00000002’ not the entire string.

Comment: It should return your wish. You can see here https://regex101.com/r/WWiauv/1 that my regex is working.